# Find truncated cells in an excel workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have performed web scraping using python of a particular section of the SEC website and exported the data in an excel file. However, due to character limit in excel, there are few cells which are truncated i.e. not all the data has been successfully extracted in those cells. Is there a way to highlight or find all these truncated cells?

Comment: during export, the website should be able to move the excess characters to the next column or row. If the file was automatically generated, there is no way to get the excess characters.

Answer (score 0):

maximum number of characters in a cell should be 32767 (Excel versions 2007 - 2016),
make a conditional formatting with the following formula:

```
=LEN($A$1)>32766
```

the formula has to be entered in:
home -> conditional formatting -> manage rules -> use a formula to determine which cell to format -> enter the formula and choose the format

[image: max characters in cell]

Comment: In case it's not obvious, you also need to adjust the range in Applies To, to take into account the entire range where the data is.

Comment: @robrados Thats great !!

Comment: @robrados I used your formula, however it works on just one cell, is there a way to apply it to the whole column? because while selecting the range I gave the whole column range it did not work

Comment: don't fixate the cell then. if you want to color the range A12:N40 your conditional formula has to be: =len(A12)>32766. without the dollar symbol. and it always has to be the first cell of your range which you want to format.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer should work for you but only for the cell `A1`.

The length of any cell which is truncated will be only `32767`. So checking if the length is greater than that value should be sufficient for you. But use the formula,

`=LEN(A1)>32766`

in conditional formatting

Comment: I used your formula, however it works on just one cell, is there a way to apply it to the whole column? because while selecting the range I gave the whole column range it did not work

Comment: @KaranKashyap `A1` is realtive and will work for all cells which you select.  If the cells are not highlighted, then it means the data is not trucated. Since we are specifying `A1` in the formula, your data should start at `A1`. If you start it in a different range, you have to change the `A1` to the starting cell of the range